# Are INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN necessary?

Tags: sql, database, join

I understand that any join can be done with a CROSS join and a WHERE clause.

I did some experiments, and it looks like placing the equality predicate inside the where clause or as the parameter of an inner join yields the same result with the same performance.

Furthermore, using inner joins does not save any typing, since the join predicate must still be specified.

I guess that the same is true for the various kinds of outer joins. Just specify that the values can be null or not null.

Can I just go with only cross joins ?

Comment: The answer is performance may not be impacted, however, readability and code clarity is hindered when you have experienced developers looking at cross joins when they are really inner joins.

Comment: No, they are not necessary. Everything can be implemented based only on cartesian products + unions and the appropiate where clauses. And performance is unrelated, a query optimiser is in most cases better in understanding your query than a human reader. Readability is more important than the number of keystrokes, your code is only typed once, but will be read hundreds of times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not any join can be done with a CROSS join and a WHERE clause.Each of the join cross, inner and outer has it's own logical significance.

1. **A cross join applies only one phase—Cartesian Product.**
2. **An inner join applies two phases—Cartesian Product and Filter.**
3. **An outer join applies three phases—Cartesian Product, Filter, and Add Outer Rows.**

A confusing aspect of queries containing an OUTER JOIN clause is whether to specify a logical expression in the ON filter or in the WHERE filter. The main difference between the two is that **ON is applied before adding outer rows** , while **WHERE is applied afterwards**. An elimination of a row from the preserved table (specified as left outer or right outer) by the ON filter is not final because it will be added back; **an elimination of a row by the WHERE filter, by contrast, is final.**

This logical difference between the ON and WHERE clauses **exists only when using an outer
join.** When you use an inner join, it doesn’t matter where you specify your logical expressions in ON clause with inner join table operator or in Where clause with cross join table operator.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is performance may not be impacted, however, readability and code clarity is hindered when you have experienced developers looking at cross joins when they are really inner joins.  Other than that it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I concur: I *never* use a CROSS JOIN when my end-semantics are an INNER JOIN. I find it too easy to accidentally miss a crucial conditional in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

You are half right in your question. You said that you tested and compared `JOIN`s and Dekart product. And the result you got is that they are equal, however about year ago I have made the same test on MySQL database and `JOIN`s was much faster. It is because SQL standart indicates how joining operation must should be implemented and that Dekart product output must the same as `INNER JOIN`.

So my advice is to use standart way to write queries because of some reasons:

1. Queries that work well on DBMS (database management system) may not work as well on another.
2. Previous versions of the same DBMS may not optimize Dekart product as well as latter.
3. And probably the most important. Query structure with `JOIN`s is much easier to read and understand that it is doing, so it is easier to modify query.

All-in-all, my advice is to use `JOIN`s instead.