# SQLite different execution time for same result

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I've got a database with movies, and I wanted to extract every person, who starred in movies from the year 2004, ordered by birth. I've tried different querys which are doing the same, but the first one takes more than 10 times longer to execute than the other. Can someone explain why this happens? (I was using the DB Browser for SQLite, but on the CLI the same thing happens)

First query (exec time about 12-13 Seconds):

```
SELECT DISTINCT people.name
FROM people 
JOIN stars ON people.id = stars.person_id 
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id 
WHERE movies.year = 2004 
ORDER BY people.birth
```

Second query (exec time about 1-2 Seconds)

```
SELECT DISTINCT people.name
FROM movies
JOIN stars ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
JOIN people ON stars.person_id = people.id
WHERE movies.year = 2004
ORDER BY people.birth
```

DB File: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARYn7h7qmkTDL7TC009ba4kYrKPXGqWb/view?usp=sharing) (Dont know where to host this any other way sorry :/ )

Comment: Well, I think in first example it makes join and after that where, while in the second one it will make where firstly, but I cannot find the proofs =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749913/which-performs-first-where-clause-or-join-clause here is a similar subject

Comment: **Runtime** and **running time** are two quite different things.

Answer (score 0):

Your database looks pretty poorly. I see missing primary keys, not a single index or the stats table. I think it is pointless to do any performance evaluation until you have the basics properly set.